# iOS HTML Rewrite?

Tags: ios, regex, webkit, url-rewriting

I've not written an iOS app and want to know if what I want to do is reasonably easy before I invest all my time in it.  The idea is simply to leverage the built-in webkit methods to write my own browser.  I've seen tutorials where this is done fairly easily.  However, the twist is I want to apply some rewrite/regex rules prior to the page rendering.  ie, you load http://example.com which is a page containing the word 'foo'.  Prior to displaying the page, the app rewrites 'foo' to 'bar' and renders.

Is this possibly to do easily without actually writing a ground-up browser?

Thanks!

Comment: First, you can't create your own browser that isn't WebKit based on iPhone. Second, the only way to do this would be javascript __after__ the page loads, which wouldn't be what you want.

Comment: ok, so this kinda conflicts with the other answer...I'm fine using webkit, but want the rewrite *before* the page loads.  is that not possible?

Comment: It is, but it could pose many problems loading the page, especially if load times are a major concern.

Comment: load time not a major concern, thanks for the follow-up answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doable (assuming you're using the standard UIWebView component to render the page), and there are a few ways you could go about it. Among them:

- You could download the HTML and parse it via Objective-C string handlers before loading it into the UIWebView
- You coud use load the HTML as-is and use the UIWebview's `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` message to "inject" javascript onto the page, manipulating the DOM itself
- You could go the Opera route, and pre-render the page via a server-side proxy before downloading it to the client.

How far down the rabbit hole you want to go would be up to you, of course. Easy is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: really if I can keep it at the complexity level of writing a firefox plugin I'll be happy.  basically I really hate that on my desktop I have firefox loaded with lots of helpful plug-ins, and I have to give those up on iOS.  so, it's a 'neccesity is the mother of invention' type scenario - something I want for myself.  I think I'll give it a try since it seems possible without committing my life to it!

Comment: @jwebm if you can come up with a nice plugin-compatible browser, that would be awesome, especially if it was something like GreaseMonkey.

Comment: Of course, getting a "pluggable" browser into the App Store would be a whole different story...  Apple's not a fan of apps that allow scripting or other "run-time interpretation."

Comment: more like I want to take the functionality of my favorite plug-ins and bake them in first. I'm sure apple would shit a brick on anything outside of the garden. ;-)